# why snowflake COPY INTO command divides to files when it's not suppose to

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Snowflake's "copy into" dividing files when I use parameters single=false and max-size=5GB,
the data i'm uploading is just a few MBs meaning it is not beyond limit.
and yet, snowflake decides to divide it to several files

according to the documentary it's not suppose to happen if max-size that i have is larger
than the data i'm sending.

my actual query:

```
copy into @some-S3-path/some-test5/
from
(select 'abcd')
    
FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = 'CSV' COMPRESSION = 'NONE' FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"')

MAX_FILE_SIZE = 10000000
overwrite = False
single=false
include_query_id = False
detailed_output = false
header = True;
```

Comment: ```Single = false``` means multiple files. Try setting it ```single = true```

Comment: I need it to be single=false so that if and only if file-size > MAX_FILE_SIZE then it will make another file with what is left

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *according to the documentary it's not suppose to happen if max-size that i have is larger than the data i'm sending.*

[COPY INTO location](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location):

> MAX_FILE_SIZE = num
>
> Definition
>
> Number (> 0) that specifies the upper size limit (in bytes) of each file to be generated in parallel per thread. **Note that the actual file size and number of files unloaded are determined by the total amount of data and number of nodes available for parallel processing.**
>
> **Snowflake utilizes parallel execution to optimize performance. The number of threads cannot be modified.**

---

> [Unloading Data to a Single File](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location#unloading-data-to-a-single-file)
>
> Unload all rows to a single data file using the SINGLE copy option:
>
> ```
> copy into @~ from HOME_SALES
> single = true;
> ```